# Definition of a drawing strategy

Tags: logic, set-theory, infinite-games

Given the following definition:

> Let $M$ be a move set and $A,B \subset M^\omega$ are disjoint, we define the winning
> conditions for the game $G(A,B)$ as follows: if the play of the game is
> $x \in M^\omega$, then player I wins if $x \in A$, player II wins if $x \in B$, and
> otherwise the game is a *draw*. A strategy $\sigma$ is *winning or drawing in*
> $G(A,B)$ *for player I* if for all strategies $\tau$ , we have that $\sigma * \tau \in A$
> or $\sigma * \tau \notin B$, respectively. A strategy $\tau$ is *winning or drawing in*
> $G(A,B)$ *for player II* if for all strategies $\sigma$, we have that $\sigma * \tau \in B$
> or $\sigma * \tau \notin A$, respectively.

what would a "drawing strategy in $G(A, B)$" mean? A strategy such that a player can *at least* play a draw (so either draw or win), or a strategy such that a player can force a draw (so the game always ends in a draw). I find the formulation of the definition a bit unclear in this regard (but maybe that's just me?), and I think these two options are not equivalent.

Comment: Note that it may be possible that a player has no winning strategy but has a win-or-draw strategy and yet has no strategy that guarantees exactly a draw! There is almost no reason one would be interested in an exactly-drawing strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A drawing strategy is one which either draws or wins against every strategy - or perhaps more snappily, one which never *loses*. The point (looking at drawing strategies for player $I$ for simplicity) is that $\sigma*\tau\not\in B$ means that player $II$ does not win the play of $\sigma$ against $\tau$ - that is, that $\sigma$ either draws against $\tau$ or wins against $\tau$.

(In particular, $\sigma*\tau\in A$ does imply, but is not implied by, $\sigma*\tau\not\in B$.)

Comment: OK, this is what I guessed. But a strategy that forces draws exclusively is strictly stronger than a drawing strategy? Is there any game theoretic interest in this kind of strategy?

Comment: @Jori I wouldn't say that. The *condition* of forcing a draw is strictly stronger than forcing a non-loss, but a *strategy* which forces a draw is less strong, in the sense of quality of strategy, than a strategy which forces a draw-or-win but sometimes allows a win. If we have the option we want to win more. So I don't see immediately what the interest in that stronger condition would be, but of course I could be missing something.